# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. | After Angular upgrade

Tags: angular, webpack, angular12, angular-upgrade

After a simple Angular Upgrade from 11 to 12, I am getting the following error for many ".HTML" files.

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently
> no loaders are configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

There is no other change in the project and also there is no custom webpack stuff.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --base-href /ui/",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --base-href /ui/ --configuration production --build-optimizer",
    "buildcontainer": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --build-optimizer --base-href=/ui/",
    "test": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --source-map=true",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "test-headless": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless --code-coverage",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner"
  },
  "private": true,
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 Chrome versions"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "~25.3.0",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "~25.3.0",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "4.10.22",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "4.1.19",
    "@angular/animations": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "12.2.16",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "1.1.4",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "5.0.2",
    "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "1.12.3",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "2.5.10",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.12",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "4.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-gauges": "3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "2.3.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "3.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler": "1.2.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "2.1.6",
    "@progress/kendo-charts": "1.15.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.5.4",
    "@progress/kendo-date-math": "1.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns": "4.12.0",
    "@progress/kendo-recurrence": "1.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-schematics": "1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "4.28.0",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "2021.3.1109",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.40.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "25.3.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "25.3.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "25.3.0",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "1.9.0",
    "angular-gridster2": "~9.3.4",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.3",
    "angular2-query-builder": "0.6.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.22.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "http-status-codes": "2.1.4",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "json-stringify-safe": "5.0.1",
    "jszip": "3.7.1",
    "jw-paginate": "1.0.4",
    "microsoft-adal-angular6": "1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-signalr": "10.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-cacheable": "1.2.5",
    "ngx-clipboard": "13.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.8.4",
    "ngx-quill": "^10.0.5",
    "ngx-slick": "0.2.1",
    "ngx-slick-fix": "0.1.3",
    "ngx-window-token": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-xml2json": "1.0.2",
    "nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "numeral": "2.0.6",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "quill-to-pdf": "1.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.3",
    "signalr": "2.4.1",
    "slick-carousel": "1.8.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.33.1",
    "toastr": "2.1.4",
    "trackable-entities": "1.0.0-alpha.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript-string-operations": "1.4.1",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {    
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/cli": "12.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.2.16",
    "@types/angular": "1.7.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "14.14.19",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-trx-reporter": "0.4.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,    
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],    
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true    
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "f4ad836f-05c5-4d33-865f-7fd9adca4abd"
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project1": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/project1",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/web.config",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/silent-refresh.html"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
              },
              "./src/styles.less",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css",
              "./node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.js",
              "node_modules/toastr/toastr.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalr.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
            "optimization": true,
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "sourceMap": false,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "extractLicenses": true,
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "budgets": [
              {
                "type": "initial",
                "maximumWarning": "1500kb",
                "maximumError": "10mb"
              },
              {
                "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                "maximumWarning": "200kb",
                "maximumError": "400kb"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
        "options": {
          "browserTarget": "project1:build"
        },
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            "browserTarget": "project1:build:production"
          }
        }
      },
      "extract-i18n": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
        "options": {
          "browserTarget": "project1:build"
        }
      },
      "test": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
        "options": {
          "codeCoverage": true,
          "main": "src/test.ts",
          "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
          "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
          "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
          "styles": [
            {
              "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
            },
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "./src/styles.less"
          ],
          "scripts": [
            "./src/assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          ],
          "assets": [
            "src/favicon.ico",
            "src/assets"
          ]
        }
      },
      "lint": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
        "options": {
          "tsConfig": [
            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
          ],
          "exclude": [
            "**/node_modules/**"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"defaultProject": "project1"
}
```

if downgraded to 11 it works fine. What could be the possible mistake ?

---

The issue is due to the following code. which works in Angular 11

```
import('src/app/modules' + this.path).then(file => {
this.component = file[this.inputProperty.componentName]
}).catch((err: any) => {
console.log('File not found:', err);
});
```

Comment: what version of node is installed?

Comment: Node version is 14

Comment: @N.K are you able to fix it? even I am also facing same issue